# How to prevent google index for a specific subpath?

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, noindex

I have my website, say www.example.com, and I want it to be indexed.
Anyway I also have one section, **www.example.com/section** that I *don't* want to be indexed.

I tried adding the following headers to the pages under that section:

```
X-Robot-Tag: noindex,nofollow
```

Moreover, my robots.txt file says:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /section/
```

I waited about 24h but, searching for "example.com section" on the google the page is still there, at the first place!

What am I doing wrong? Isn't there any way to prevent indexing only a specific section?

Comment: "X-Robot-Tag: noindex,nofollow" - It should be `X-Robots-Tag` (with an `s`).

Comment: "I waited about 24h" - It can take longer than 24h for pages to be _removed_ from the index. It depends how often Google is crawling your site.

Comment: "can longer than 24h" should say "can take months".   The first pages could be removed in 24 hours, but if you are trying to remove thousands of pages, it could will likely take months until Googlebot gets around to re-crawling every single one of them to see the tags you have put in.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending Google two conflicting commands: you are telling them to NOINDEX some pages but then you are also preventing them from reading the NOINDEX header by blocking them from crawling these pages (in the robots.txt) so they can't see the NOINDEX command.

You should only use the NOINDEX tag and let their bots crawl your website in order to see it;

remove the:

```
Disallow: /section/
```

from your robots.txt file and next time they crawl your website, they will see the NOINDEX tag and will know not to index these pages (of course, they can still decide to INDEX these pages based on other signals, such as backlinks, but this is the correct, technical implementation).

Comment: "they can still decide to INDEX these pages based on other signals, such as backlinks" - not if `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` is set. That would apply if the page was blocked by `robots.txt`.

Comment: The robots file can only prevent crawling, so yes, backlinks can make them indexed but the NOINDEX tag is also not a guarantee, I have a few cases from different websites that even with the tag in place, Google decided to index the page (rare but still happens)

Comment: So robots.txt is useless? If I remove robots.txt and just leave the noindex would solve my problem?

Comment: Robots.txt is very important, it just shouldn't be used to NOINDEX pages, so yes, you can remove the command I mentioned.